# Drupal views php field collection value

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, view

I am using Drupal 7.

In a node, I have a field collection, and in that field collection I have a field called 'amount' which is an integer field.

When I try to display this value within a view column using 'Views PHP' module, in the available variables it appears as

$row->field_amount: Field collection item: amount

However when I print/echo this, the value that appears is not correct. It seems to show the ID of the field collection or so.

On extra note, the view is a taxonomy view. It is deriving the field collection field using a relationship to the node.

How can I get it to show the actual value inserted in views php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a common "bug" of the Views PHP module... you'll only get the nid of the node!

if this is not a high-traffic/performance site, i recommend you to load the node in the view field and access the value via the node-variable..

for example:

```
<?php
    $node = node_load($row->field_amount);
    echo $node->field_amount['und'][0]['value'];
?>
```

that code is not tested, but i hope, you get the idea...

if you are not sure, how to access the data, you definitely should install the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module...
with devel, you can nicely print out the variable like:

```
<?php
    dpm($node);
?>
```

and find the right value...

as far as i know, there is no other way with the Vies PHP module... sorry

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used the devel module and tracked down the output value. Then I was able to retrieve the actual value by using:

$data->field_field_amount[0]['raw']['value'];